# RDS performance on alter table

Tags: mysql, performance, rds

I'm doing some performance testing on RDS with MySQL 5.5 My test consists of running liquibase changesets (mostly alters, some updates, some create table) on big table ( most tables have millions of rows).

I did some tests with db.r3.2xlarge instances, but cannot reach a good performance when I compare to the hardware we have here. I seem to be capped on the I/O during the alter table statement. Here is a screenshot of my test with a instance having 1000 provisioned IOPS:
[db.r3.2xlarge with 1000 IOPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0AnK.png).

I even tested with a db.m4.10xlarge with a 3 TB storage, giving me 30 000 IOPS. But again, I got maxed out at 3000 IOPS (instead of the 30 000). I seems that I was then maxed out on the CPU (2.5% X 40 CPU = 100% on 1 CPU). See the graphs of my test [db.m4.10xlarge with 30000 iops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fkg3.jpg)

Any idea what I can do to improve the speed of those alter? Right now, my old hardware is beating the migration time of AWS which kinda surprises me...

Comment: gp2 SSD is 3 IOPS/GB sustained, so 3 TB is 3000 IOPS, not 30000.  gp2 caps out at 10K IOPS.

Comment: But those tests were done via Provisioned IOPS.